# Angular directives with and without []?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-template

[I'm reviewing this tutorial](https://netbasal.com/create-advanced-components-in-angular-e0655df5dde6) which uses a `tooltip` directive like this:

#### CASE A: No surrounding []

```
  <p tooltip="Tooltip from text">Tooltip from text</p>
```

#### CASE B: Surrounding []

```
  <p [tooltip]="template">Tooltip from TemplateRef</p>
```

I just want to make sure I understand this correctly.

If we use the `tooltip` directive without brackets, then the text string gets passed to the directive (`Tooltip from text"`).

When we surround the tooltip with brackets, then the `template` property, which should be available on the component view (The view using the directive), gets passed in?

Comment: wrapping an HTML attribute/property with `[]` or `()` or `[()]` will cause whatever is in the following quotes to be evaluated as an **expression**. A plain html attribute/property will just be evaluated as a string as it normally would in a non-angular context. This also explains why you can't use things like `if` statements, `switch` statements, `try`/`catch`,  etc. inside the quotes of property binding. It can only handle expressions.

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax? Also note the text *in the elements* in the tutorial.

Comment: It's a good read.  When I'm looking at intersections of Angular concepts like directives and template syntax I like to make sure that I lock down the concept with a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we use the tooltip directive without brackets, then the text string gets passed to the directive

Yes Exactly.

For the second case,  `[tooltip]="template"`

[prop] is for object binding to properties (`@Input()` of an Angular component or directive or a property of a DOM element) of the  angular Component.